# Internet Explorer 11 automatically retrying failed ajax requests

Tags: xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

I have a single-page app built using React, and I've noticed intermittent issues from users who are using Internet Explorer 11, where IE is repeating ajax requests multiple times (which is an issue given that the API in question is not idempotent).

The most common case I've seen are where the request errors out with a "Network Error" Error, but IE retries the request multiple times. I've been able to recreate this using Fiddler and having it just drop those requests, in which case I can see multiple requests being made, although the network tab in IE dev tools only shows a single request. This also only seems to occur after a successful request, so this may be related to persistent connections?

The single page app is using axios, but I've been able to get it to occur with fetch and straight XHR as well, so I'm assuming this is something in IE11 itself. So the questions I'm trying to answer are:

- Is this intended functionality, or is it a quirk of IE11?
- Is there any way to configure or control this behaviour?

Comment: Does this issue only occur if the requests get failed? I try to test the issue with IE 11 but it is not sending the request multiple times. If possible try to provide the sample code and let us know which OS build and which exact version of the IE 11 browser you are using on your side. It can help us to reproduce the issue. Thanks for your understanding.